# Is there a better way to make a game loop than 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval'

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-loop

I wanted to know if there's a smoother and lighter way to make animations with a loop.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[NSTimeInterval] target:[target] selector:@selector() userInfo:[UInfo] repeats:[BOOL]];
```

Is there a better way than that makes the animation smoother or is it that I'm testing on the iOS simulator on the Mac?

Comment: There about 30 (OK maybe a half dozen) different ways to do time intervals in iOS.

Comment: Yeah but if you look closely you can read 'better' not simply other ways...

Comment: are you using sprite kit? https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) will let you trigger your work when the display refreshes; that's probably the best thing to use for this.